# How to calculate the difference between two numbers in a sequence that wraps around?

Tags: arithmetic, computer-arithmetic

I am dealing with a problem that has a solution in this simplified problem's solution.

Assume there is a sequence of numbers 0-99. There is a wrap-around such 99+1 = 0 and 0-1=99. The position 100 and 0 overlap. The diagram below will help to visualize this. The number 10 is shown so the scenarios mentioned below are easier to visualize.

[image]

We want to calculate the difference between two numbers to find the shortest way to get from A to B.

```
Scenario 1;
B = 75 (end)
A = 50 (start)
Shortest path is clockwise B-A=25, starting at A=50

Scenario 2;
B=50 (end)
A=75 (start)
Shortest path is anti-clockwise B-A=-25, starting at A=75
```

So far so good, now for the trouble.

```
Scenario 3;
B=10 (end)
A=75 (start)
Shortest path would be clockwise 10+25=35; starting at A=75
But what is the formula?

Scenario 4;
B=75 (end)
A=10 (start)
Shortest path would be anti-clockwise -10-25=-35; starting at A=10
But what is the formula?
```

When going from A to B requires to go over the wrap around point, the simple formula A-B or B-A does not work anymore. So what is the formula that will work with all the scenarios to give the correct sign and the magnitude to move? +ve sign is clockwise while -ve sign is anti-clockwise.

EDIT:

Since I have to implement a hardware design, it is important to be able to not use division or modulus. Only multiplication, addition and subtraction can be used.

Comment: As in $(B-A)\bmod 100$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to implement this in hardware, is there a longer method that does not use division or modulus and only uses addition, subtraction and multiplication?

Comment: Compute $\;d:=B-A\;$ if $d\le-50$ add $100$ else if $d>50$ subract $100$.